# How to use cartodb.js to create layer - not just tilelayer - from named map

Tags: carto, carto-js

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119279/example-of-how-to-display-a-cartodb-layer-using-the-layergroupid-after-initial) gis.stackexchange question asks how a layer can be displayed after initializing a named map.

I don't have enough reputation to ask a follow-up comment to javisantana's response.  It reads in part:

```
Why didn't you use cartodb.js to get that layergroup? if you are going to use 
cartodb.js it's better to use it to get that layergroup
```

My question is:  *how* do you use cartodb.js to do that?  I can do it just fine using the instructions on the [Maps API page](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/maps-api.html) and can also successfully create a leaflet tileLayer in a fashion similar to that which javisantana's suggests.  However, I would love to be able to use cartodb.js and then be able to do a bit more than just display a static tileLayer (e.g. replace the named map's template variables at client run time).

It seems like it *might* be possible to do this calling cartodb.createLayer, but my attempts to provide `layermetadata` have not been successful.  The documentation on the [cartodb.js page](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#cartodbcreatelayermap-layersource--options--callback) is a little unclear:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, { layermetadata })
Layer metadata is always in the form: { type: 'LAYER_TYPE_NAME', options: {...} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need the layergroupid, I guess you are trying to create a layer and then change the values.

creating a layer is a simple as this:

`cartodb.createLayer(map, {
          user_name: 'examples',
          type: 'cartodb',
          sublayers: [{
             sql: 'select * from country_boundaries',
             cartocss: '#layer { polygon-fill: #F00; polygon-opacity: 0.3; line-color: #F00; }'
          }]
        })`

full example here: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/examples/leaflet_multilayer.html

If you have a named map and you want to change the template params the way to do is:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, {
          type: 'namedmap',
          user_name: 'documentation',
          options: {
            named_map: {
              name: 'tpl_b47ff8ec_e7eb_11e3_894f_0e230854a1cb'
            }
          } })
```

In order to change template params you should use setParam:

`cartodb.createLayer(map, {....}).done(function(layer) {
    layer.setParam('test', 1);
  })`

see the doc at:
http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#layersetparamskey-value

Comment: Thank you.  The latter part that pertained to the named map is what I was looking for.  I know the documentation is a work in progress, but it does leave a bit to be desired.  Is there anywhere I can find, for instance, a thorough explanation of all of the options that can be passed as the `{layermetadata}` json object when calling createLayer?  For example, how would I have known to pass "named_map : {name: 'mynamedmap'}"?

Comment: I was confused and thought I needed the layergroupid, though i see from your response that I didn't.  I have since edited my answer to remove the layergroupid aspect in case others are interested more generally

Comment: @susiederkins we are working on "layermetadata" doc lately. Thanks for your feedback